# What is the difference between standardisation and normalisation in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to train a SVM and KNN model, I was wondering if anyone could advise for training a Machine Learning model which processing is more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization rescales the values into a range of [0,1], Standardization rescales data to have a mean (μ) of 0 and standard deviation (σ) of 1.

It's recommended to use Standardization before applying KNN, check [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/why-is-scaling-required-in-knn-and-k-means-8129e4d88ed7) for some explanation.